# yii2: how to creating a back link button

Tags: button, yii2, back

I'm new in Yii2 and I'm not able to find something to do a back button in Yii2,
I found the solution in Yii1 is:

```
echo CHtml::link('Back',Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
```

but I'm not able to find a solution in Yii2,
can you help me?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
   echo \yii\helpers\Html::a( 'Back', Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

Comment: This code doing good but in case user directly open any link then "Back" button not working because at that time referrer is empty.

Comment: @SunnyTecho In that case you can hide the Back button.

Comment: Also can make a mess in cases where it can make a circular back, like when using pagination. You will enter a loop

Comment: @moplin Yes It can be a mess sometimes, so in those cases, we should not use it.

Answer (score 4):

Yii2 provides [remember URLs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html#remember-urls) functionality:

```
// Remember current URL 
Url::remember();

// Remember URL specified. See Url::to() for argument format.
Url::remember(['product/view', 'id' => 42]);

// Remember URL specified with a name given
Url::remember(['product/view', 'id' => 42], 'product');
```

In the next request we can get URL remembered in the following way:

```
$url = Url::previous();
$productUrl = Url::previous('product');
```